# PDO result is empty but query returns data through MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT Username,Level FROM users WHERE Username = :username";
print $sql;
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':username' => $username));
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($data);
```

No data is printed but when I copy the result of print $sql into MySQL and run the query (replacing :username with a value that is in that column) I get a result.

Why is this not retrieving data?

Edit: $username comes from a form, so I do:

```
$username = $_POST['username']; // print $username shows entered value
```

My connection is not the issue, I call a function to return the right connection based on the parameter

```
$debh = getConnection('read'); // creates connection with user with select privs
```

Inside getConnection:

```
    case "read":
        $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbName . '', "$readUser", "$readUserPassword");
        break;
```

Comment: can I see the database connection `new PDO (...)`

Comment: How do you initialize $username?

Comment: After the execution you can check for `$sth->errorInfo()` to see if you missed something

Comment: can you also `print_r($_POST);` and see if `$_POST['username'];` isset. I dont see that check anywhere (at least what you posted). My solution past a static value, just for testing purpose

Comment: For the sake of getting this working I manually set $username but still no output.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting on your error_log `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbh in ...`

Comment: You are not returning your connection, just setting it to a random variable - `$connection = new PDO(...); break`. Try returning it `$connection = new PDO(...);  return $connection; break`. Also, is `$debh` a copy/paste error here, as it is supposed to be `$dbh`

Comment: Sean I return $connection

Comment: try this change instance of `dbh` to `debh` or change `$debh = getConnection('read');` to `$dbh = getConnection('read');`

Comment: mispelling, sorry for the typo

Comment: still same issue or fix?

Comment: same, I think it has something to do with function scope. getConnection() is one level up from this file's directory. If I set the connection just above my posted code this works.

Comment: I think you answer your own question, good night

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$username = 'user@email.com';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stackoverflow;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$sql = "SELECT Username,Level FROM users WHERE Username = :username";
print $sql;
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':username' => $username));
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($data);
```

- Make sure to change the database credentials
- `user@email.com` is an user in my database